# Bison in the plural form

Tags: plural-forms

I just realized that we should say "bison are this and that" without the plural "s". I've checked its definition in a dictionary and it's a countable noun. I've seen in a textbook "Bison are..." and on the same page in the same textbook "Chimpanzees are..." so what am I missing?

Comment: Some English names of animals are the same in both singular and plural, notably _sheep_ and _deer_. Also, some herd animals are often referred to in the singular form - _a herd of buffalo_.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes they are just like that. I'm not sure why, but I've learned to accept how they are, learn them that way and move on. I've been told that English has many rules but does not keep to them.